# Pass value from Mono/Flux to methods

Tags: java, mongodb, reactive-programming, reactor

I'm new to reactive programming concept. I'm following the "Learning Spring Boot 2.0" and the described simple concepts/examples are understandable. But I don't get how to use Mono/Flux in more complex use cases. 
Some example with  with spring boot, mongo and project reactor

My model

```
User
@Id
private String id;
private String login;

Comment
@Id
private ObjectId _id;
private String content;
private String ownerLogin;
```

so this simple example to get comments by owner works fine

```
@GetMapping(params = "login")
@ResponseBody
public Flux<Comment> getAllCommentsByLogin(@RequestParam("login") String login) {
    return commentRepository.findByOwnerLogin(login);
};
```

But if I would slightly change the model to store owner by entity id, it would be not so ease to retrieve the comments by owner

```
Comment
@Id
private ObjectId _id;
private String content;
private String ownerId;
```

my intention is to make rest controller easy to use by end user and first find the user entity by login and if exists all user comments

```
@GetMapping(params = "login")
@ResponseBody
public Flux<Comment> getAllCommentsByLogin(@RequestParam("login") String login) {
    return commentRepository.findByOwnerId(userRepository.findByLogin(login).map(user2 -> user2.getId())
};
```

this soulution is obviously wrong, but I don't know if the whole approach is wrong or only this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's hope your `userRepository.findByLogin()` returns `Mono<User>`, then code should be like this:

```
return userRepository.findByLogin(login)
               .flatMapMany(user -> commentRepository.findByOwnerId(user.getId()));
```

Comment: Yes `userRepository` returns `Mono<User>`. And your code is exactly what I was looking for.